# IntelliJ IDEA dpi scaling

Tags: windows-7, display, resolution, intellij-idea, android-studio

I have a Windows 7 computer with a 768p display. This means there is very little room for the content. Developing apps in Android studio is an absolute nightmare since, with all the side windows which are constantly required during development, the actual area where I can write the code is literally just a little square.

One way around that I can think of is lowering the DPI of the display which will give the programs the perception that they are running on a higher resolution display. I did lower the DPI. It affected Firefox browser, which now thinks it's running on a 1080p display, but Android studio/IntelliJ IDEA is still taking the same scaling.

The question is how can I lower the scaling of the Android studio or the screen so I can see more content on the screen?

Comment: DPI scaling is up to the developer of the application to support.

Comment: I am looking for hacks/workarounds